# Linux Mint Godot window when ran very small

Tags: godot, linux

I am running my game on Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon. When I run my game I get a very small window that is about 1 pixel tall. This happens across all projects. I have tried uninstalling Godot and reinstalling it from the package manager. I have also tried the official launcher from their website. Updating through update manager does not help as well. I get the same issue using Godot 3.2.2 and 3.2.3
[image: example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to enable DPI in my display menu